# search for strings and subheadings in org heading

Tags: org-mode, helm, search

As my org files keep growing, it is getting more complicated to find what I'm looking for. For now I'm using `helm-occur` to find strings and `helm-org-in-buffer-headings` to find headings in org files. However I want to be able to limit the scope of the search to the current heading including subheadings.

I have found `helm-org-parent-headings`, but I couldn't find "helm-org-child-headings".

**EDIT**

The command `org-narrow-to-subtree` mentioned by Tobias is a good solution, however I'm looking for a command that does not change the contents of the org buffer (I still can't figure out how to return to the "original" buffer without killing the buffer created by `org-narrow-to-subtree`).

`helm-org-parent-headings` displays headings like `helm-org-in-buffer-headings` WITHOUT changing the buffer, but as the name suggests it only displays parents.

So what I am looking for is a command that does the opposite and only displays children of the heading in a helm buffer.

Furthermore I want to modify `helm-occur` to search only for strings, that belong to children of the heading at point.

Comment: Maybe you can use `org-narrow-to-subtree`.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for a solution similiar to `helm-org-parent-headings`.

Comment: Explain what your comment means in the question body: Just what behavior are you looking for? Describe what `helm-org-parent-headings` does, for which you want something similar.

Comment: You need to "widen" the buffer to undo the narrowing. Either use:
M-x widen
or C-x n w
You can narrow with C-x n s

It looks like helm-org-in-buffer-headings temporarily widens your buffer, so you are going to have to write your own code to get what you want.

Comment: As @JohnKitchin and @Tobias, I recommend to use narrowing. If you're struggeling with getting back to the original buffer (aka widening), I recommend to use `narrow-or-widen-dwim` that Artur Malabarba kindly shared in his blog some time ago: http://endlessparentheses.com/emacs-narrow-or-widen-dwim.html Narrowing and widening can then be done with one and the same key.  Artur Malabarba binds it to `C-x n`, but it's easy to change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following commands search within current heading or within current top level heading when called with prefix argument:

```
(require 'rx)
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun org-goto-top-level+ ()
  (let ((rx (rx bol "*" (one-or-more (not (any "*"))) eol)))
    (or  (looking-at rx)
         (re-search-backward rx nil t)
         (re-search-forward rx nil t))))

(defun helm-occur-current+ (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((opos (point)))
    (when (or (not arg)
              (org-goto-top-level+))
      (save-restriction
        (org-narrow-to-subtree)
        (helm-occur))
      (when (= helm-exit-status 1)
        (goto-char opos)))))

(defun helm-org-in-current-headings+ (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((opos (point)))
    (when (or (not arg)
              (org-goto-top-level+))
      (save-restriction
        (org-narrow-to-subtree)
        (cl-letf (((symbol-function #'buffer-base-buffer)
                   ;; see `helm-org--get-candidates-in-file'
                   ;; this prevents it from widening the buffer
                   (lambda (&rest _) t)))
          (helm-org-in-buffer-headings)))
      (when (= helm-exit-status 1)
        (goto-char opos)))))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite the same as `helm-occur`, but the agenda is a useful tool to find things.  Agenda searches can be restricted to the current buffer or subtree using `<` in the [agenda dispatcher](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-dispatcher.html#Agenda-dispatcher).  `C-c a < <` will restrict the agenda search to just the current subtree.  You can search for tags, properties or just strings.

Answer (score 0):

[John Kitchin](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9134/john-kitchin) proposed in his comment that you should write your own function to get exactly what you want.
I assume you want to call occur for the current sub-tree of org.

Maybe the following example is sufficient for you or it gives you a starter.

Just copy-paste the code in your [emacs init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

After evaluating the init file or after re-starting emacs you can place point in one of the headers of an org file and run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-occur-children` <kbd>RET</kbd> in the same way as you would run `occur`.

```el
(require 'org)
(defun org-occur-children (regexp &optional nlines)
  "Run occur only in current org subtree.
See `occur' for the meaning of the arguments and for interactive calls."
  (interactive (occur-read-primary-args))
  (save-restriction
    (org-narrow-to-subtree)
    (funcall #'occur regexp nlines)))
```